# Row column value in TwoDArrayWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I emitted 2 D double array as value from mapper and tried to access that in reducer.converted back to double for getting sum of all 2D array.

```
public static class DoubleTwoDArrayWritable extends TwoDArrayWritable {
        public DoubleTwoDArrayWritable () { 
             super (DoubleWritable.class) ;
        }
    }
```

Reducer

```
public class ReducerSvm extends Reducer<Text, DoubleTwoDArrayWritable, Text, Text>{
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<DoubleTwoDArrayWritable> values,Context context){
        System.out.println("key------"+key.toString());
        Writable [][] getArray = null;
        double C[][] = new double[3][1];
        for (DoubleTwoDArrayWritable value : values)
        {
            getArray = value.get();
            for (int i=0; i<3 ; i++ )
            {
                for (int j=0 ; j<1 ; j++ ){
                    System.out.println("v--> "+((DoubleWritable)getArray[i][j]).get());
                    C[i][j] = ((DoubleWritable)getArray[i][j]).get();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("C array");
            for (int i=0; i<3 ; i++ ){
                for (int j=0 ; j<1 ; j++ ){
                    System.out.println(C[i][j]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```

I am able to get my double array in Reducer .But I `hardcoded` my row and values.
How to get `row` and `column` count in reducer while using `TwoDArrayWritable`

**EDIT:**

As Balduz adviced I edited the code

```
public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<DoubleTwoDArrayWritable> values,Context context){

        for (DoubleTwoDArrayWritable value : values) {
            Writable[][] currentArray = value.get();
            int rowSize = currentArray.length;
            int columnSize = currentArray[0].length;
            System.out.println("row size: "+rowSize);
            double[][] myArray = new double[rowSize][columnSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; i < currentArray[i].length; j++) {
                     myArray[i][j] = ((DoubleWritable)currentArray[i][j]).get();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("myArray array");
            for (int i=0; i<myArray.length ; i++ ){
                for (int j=0 ; j<myArray[0].length ; j++ ){
                    System.out.println(myArray[i][j]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }
}
}
```

I am able to get the rowsize correctly.

But showing

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at edu.am.bigdata.svmmodel.ReducerTrail.reduce(ReducerTrail.java:26)
    at edu.am.bigdata.svmmodel.ReducerTrail.reduce(ReducerTrail.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:449)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please don't call a variable `getArray`, as it leads to confusion because it looks like a method name. To iterate over each of the matrices, you need to do the following:

```
for (DoubleTwoDArrayWritable value : values) {
    Writable[][] currentArray = value.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < currentArray[i].length; j++) {
             DoubleWritable valueYouWant = (DoubleWritable)currentArray[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
To store the whole matrix in a variable, I assume every row has the same number of columns. In that case you could initialize it like this:

```
for (DoubleTwoDArrayWritable value : values) {
    Writable[][] currentArray = value.get();
    int rowSize = currentArray.length;
    int columnSize = currentArray[0].length;
    double[][] myArray = new double[rowSize][columnSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < currentArray[i].length; j++) {
             myArray[i][j] = ((DoubleWritable)currentArray[i][j]).get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes Balduz. But I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 in      myArray[i][j] = ((DoubleWritable)currentArray[i][j]).get();

Comment: Edit your question and paste the whole code you are using in the reducer, the one you have tried and is giving you the index out bounds exception.

Comment: Check edit.And If I am not wrong.myArray should be declared outside for (DoubleTwoDArrayWritable value : values) {.Inorder to get my full array.Else for each iteration i only get one value.

Comment: Ok, sorry... I couldn't find the error until I saw it. I wrote in the inner loop that the condition should be `i < currentArray[i].length`, but that is wrong. Change the `i` for `j` and that will do. `i` is for the rows and `j` for the columns, and since there are more rows than columns, and I wrote the inner condition wrong, you are trying to access more columns than what there actually are. Sorry for that! I have edited my post so that there is no more confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58956/discussion-between-sreeveni-and-balduz).

Comment: While taking the sum of all 2D arrray it doesnot give the sum.[ myArray[i][j] += ((DoubleWritable)currentArray[i][j]).get();]

Comment: If you want to get the sum, then you will need to define the variable outside the for loop so that you don't replace the value in each iteration.

Comment: so again I need to take a copy and then sum the matrix right.Is that a good way?As I need the sum of the matrix so it will also be a 2D array

Comment: Yes, define the 2D double array `myArray`outside of the loop, and then in each of the iteration add the values to it. However the problem is when initializing it, as you don't know the dimensions until inside of the loop. Create an if whose condition is if the array is null, and if true then initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Expose two methods in the writable key DoubleTwoDArrayWritable, and call this two methods from the reducer to get the information.

```
public static class DoubleTwoDArrayWritable extends TwoDArrayWritable {
    public DoubleTwoDArrayWritable () { 
         super (DoubleWritable.class) ;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        Writable[][] 2dArray = super.get();
        return 2dArray.length;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        Writable[][] 2dArray = super.get();
        return 2dArray[0].length;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.